# Highlighting the first Item in ComboBox without Selecting

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have a custom Behavior attached to a ComboBox control.

In the behavior I want to, by default, highlight the first item of the ComboBox implementing incremental search. I mean the moment result render in the popup the first item should get highlighted but NOT selected.

That means I cannot use `SelectedIndex = 0` because it will also select the item. I want to keep the ComboBox empty but set the visual state of the item to highlighted one.

I see there is a `IsHighlightedProperty` in `ComboBoxItem` but that is registered as a readonly dp so not helping.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about highlighting? Are we talking `[Highlighted[v]]` or keep the combo empty, but change the color of the first item to appear highlighted?

Comment: surely, I want to keep the combobox empty but change the color of the first item to appear highlighted..

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a converter you can also use the ComboBox's `AlternationIndex` property to get an index on your items, then use a trigger to color just the first one. Set the alternation index to something that will always be larger than the number of items in the ComboBox so that only one item will have an index of 0. The style to highlight the item would be something like:

```
    <Style x:Key="FirstColor" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ComboBox.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>            
    </Style>
```

And your ComboBox will look something like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="-1" 
          AlternationCount="500" 
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FirstColor}"/>
```

The `HighlightBrushKey` will use the existing highlight style rather than a custom color.

Comment: I need to do this from a Behavior. I do not want to modify the existing control.

Answer (score 0):

The list of your items should be some kind of `ItemsControl` (i.e. `ComboBox`, `ListBox`, `ListView`, `TreeView` etc.) right?

So it must have an `ItemTemplate` property in it...

So in that `ItemTemplate` 
         add a `DataTrigger` that will be having 
                  `MultiBinding` to two properties...

1. The current data context of the list item ... `{Binding}`
2. The ItemsSource of the list ... `{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncetsrType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}`

The `MultiBinding.Converter` will return true if

```
  values[0] == ((IEnumerable)values[1]).Cast<object>().First()
```

Then based on this flag in the `DataTrigger` you can apply whatever styles you want to the that first item in the list!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I may not want to set style but want to set the comboboxitem highlighted and it should use the existing style for highlighting.